# When I use "FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow" itremoves the entire value of TextFormField

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am using the below code to allow only alphanumeric and some special characters in TextFormField, but when the user types any other characters the entire TextFormField is cleared how to avoid clearing entire user input

```
inputFormatters: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]+$'))
        ],
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:

```
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]+'))
  ],
```

The Dollar sign ($) at the end is causing the problem.

Comment: it's working, thank you

Comment: can you explain a bit why is that?

Comment: @davidebubz The dollar sign at the end of regex means the end of the string which causes the textfield to clear when any invalid character is typed as the whole string should match the regex. to prevent this you should remove $ from the end.

Comment: @MortezaMohammadi why does the "end of string" causes text field to be cleared?

Comment: @Shubham if the RegExp includes $ (end of string), the formatter checks the entire string as one unit. If it doesn't match, the entire input is cleared. Without $, it checks character sequences and removes characters until a match is found.

Comment: @MortezaMohammadi thanks, also I notice the same issue if you type a non-matching character in between some already typed text. eg type some matching text like 123456 and then type a non-matching character in between 123<here>456 and anything after, along with, the non-matching character, like 456 here, will be removed. Using Form may be an alternative but I would prefer to bypass this issue if anyone can suggest a way to do it.

Comment: @Shubham Yes, as I said it keeps removing characters from the end of the string till it finally matches the RegExp.